# How I can do this query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**table1:**

```
name    added_by     edited_by
a       1            3
b       2            2
c       3            1
```

**table2:**

```
id    login
1     admin 
2     user1 
3     user2
```

**I need this result:**

```
name    added_by     edited_by
a       admin        user2
b       user1        user1
c       user2        admin
```

Comment: Did you try anything to get this result?

Comment: If you try it yourself, it is pretty easy with 2 joins.

Comment: @Mono I only see 2 tables.

Comment: @Daerik you can join one table 2 times on different foreign keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       t2.login AS added_by, 
       t3.login AS edited_by 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON(t1.added_by=t2.id) 
INNER JOIN table2 t3 
    ON(t1.edited_by=t3.id)
```